# Fetch website mobile version?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

currently I'm fetching a website just by its normal address by

```
Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

But I wonder if I could somehow optimize the network data by forching a fetch to a eg mobile version? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the website has a mobile version it will usually (at their end) detect the browser type and serve up a mobile version automatically.

Otherwise, you could just use the mobile url of the website where you pass the url.