# Check if website has a mobile version programatically. (Python/PHP)

Tags: php, python, mobile

Lets say i have a incoming website request with a url of desktop version
of website.
I'd like to detect if this website has a mobile version.

According to this answer [Fetch website mobile version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629265/fetch-website-mobile-version) most of what i have to do is to set User Agent to some mobile phone and server will serve the mobile version.

I think i could also check m.domain.com and mobile.domain.com.

But here's question:
How would i know if server responded with mobile version?
Are there other ways of getting mobile version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a one size fits all answer to your question. You could use curl to hit the domain with a couple different user agents and see if different content is returned for mobile vs desktop, or see if you are redirected for either.